# Vault Error, Server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm using Hashicorp vault as a secrets store and installed it via apt repository on Ubuntu 20.04.

After that, I added the root key to access the UI and I'm able to add or delete secrets using UI.

Whenever I'm trying to add or get a secret using the command line, I get the following error :

```
jarvis@saki:~$ vault kv get secret/vault 
Get "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/internal/ui/mounts/secret/vault": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

My vault config looks like this :

```
# Full configuration options can be found at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration

ui = true

#mlock = true
#disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/opt/vault/data"
}

#storage "consul" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
#  path    = "vault"
#}

# HTTP listener
#listener "tcp" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
#  tls_disable = 1
#}

# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.crt"
  tls_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.key"
}

# Example AWS KMS auto unseal
#seal "awskms" {
#  region = "us-east-1"
#  kms_key_id = "REPLACE-ME"
#}

# Example HSM auto unseal
#seal "pkcs11" {
#  lib            = "/usr/vault/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so"
#  slot           = "0"
#  pin            = "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
#  key_label      = "vault-hsm-key"
#  hmac_key_label = "vault-hsm-hmac-key"
#}
```

Comment: You should show your vault config.

Comment: It's in `/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl`. Even then, it won't be configured for production use, you need to do that yourself. I recommend you take the [vault tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-install).

Comment: I've edited the post, does it offer any help to find out what the problem is?

Comment: can you try just calling `curl -v https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status` and show us the result?

Comment: Also, can you confirm if the files `/opt/vault/tls/tls.crt` and `/opt/vault/tls/tls.key` exist?

Comment: It worked, I had to export the root token to be able to add and fetch data using in memory dev server, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Though the exception can be common to more than one similar problem, I fixed the problem by exporting the root token generated after running this command :

```
vault server -dev
```

The output is like this

```
...

You may need to set the following environment variable:

    $ export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'

The unseal key and root token are displayed below in case you want to
seal/unseal the Vault or re-authenticate.

Unseal Key: 1+yv+v5mz+aSCK67X6slL3ECxb4UDL8ujWZU/ONBpn0=
Root Token: s.XmpNPoi9sRhYtdKHaQhkHP6x

Development mode should NOT be used in production installations!
...
```

Then just export these variables by running the following commands :

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
```

```
export VAULT_TOKEN="s.XmpNPoi9sRhYtdKHaQhkHP6x"
```

Note: Replace "s.XmpNPoi9sRhYtdKHaQhkHP6x" with your token received as output from the above command.

Then run the following command to check the status :

```
vault status
```

Again, the error message can be similar for many different problems.

Comment: Only exporting the VAULT_ADDR worked for me

Comment: The reason this works is because you do not start vault with `sudo`. I.e. `vault server -dev` instead of `sudo vault server -dev`. See https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/1714

Answer (score 15):

In PowerShell on Windows 10, I was able to set it this way:

```
$Env:VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
```

Then

```
vault status
```

returned correctly. This was on Vault 1.7.3 in dev mode

You can echo VAULT_ADDR by specifying it on the command line and pressing enter - same as the set line above but omitting the = sign and everything after it

```
$Env:VAULT_ADDR
```

Output:

> Key             Value
> ---             ----- Seal Type       shamir Initialized     true Sealed          false Total Shares    1 Threshold       1 Version
> 1.7.3 Storage Type    inmem Cluster Name    vault-cluster-80649ba2 Cluster ID      2a35e304-0836-2896-e927-66722e7ca488 HA Enabled
> false

Comment: Same as Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

For production, you can just add VAULT_ADDR to the environment variable.

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

Answer (score 0):

for windows cmd:

```
set VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

Answer (score -4):

Try using a new terminal window. This worked for me